# Did Littlefinger hire the Catspaw assassin?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In "The Dragon and the Wolf" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E07), the Stark kids know that it wasn't Tyrion who owned Baelish's former dagger that was used to attempt to assassinate Bran. Their unsaid assumption seems to be that Petyr was behind the whole thing. However, we know in the books that it was Robert who owned the dagger which Joffery stole.

So, did Petyr's trial reveal that it was him who ordered Bran's assassination (which Bran would presumably have found out using his greensight abilities) and not Joffery, the most popular theory?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question; the book and show are two different continuities. So the guilty person in one continuity isn't necessarily the guilty person in the other.

Comment: @onewho True. But the shows and books were more or less similar in the very beginning

Comment: That seemed strange to me as well, throwing in that the dagger was Petyrs. Which Petyr actually already said in the show, with the lie that Tyrion won it from him on a wager. In the books both of those statements were a lie as you said. In the show now I'm not sure. Maybe they were trying to tie up one more loose end, though Petyr was down in King's Landing and couldn't have known Bran was crippled to order the assassination so it makes very little sense to pin it on him.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After watching the scene again, there was no assumption that the Stark kids thought Baelish was behind Bran's assassination attempt. The accusation being pointed at him in this case was simply that he had outright lied to Catelyn Stark by saying Tyrion had owned it.

Comment: Especially since it was the belief that Tyrion owned the dagger that prompted Catelyn to imprison Tyrion. This resulted in Jamie killing all Ned's men and injuring his leg, but especially in the escalation of the Lannister-Stark conflict which eventually led to war.

Comment: How did they know that he lied to Catelyn?  How did Catelyn tell Sansa / Bran / Arya that LF said it was Tyrions?  Yes Bran can see, but he didn't say he went there so we don't know..